# Table gets deleted when trying to overwrite the data in it from databricks spark

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, spark-jdbc

I am trying to write dataframe data into a table in Azure SQL from Databricks using pyspark.
Table : dbo.test already exists in the database. I am able to read it before I execute below write operation.

```
testDf.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode("overwrite")\
        .option("truncate", "false")\
        .option("url", azure_sql_url).option("dbtable", 'dbo.test')\
        .option("databaseName", database_name)\
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("encrypt", "true")\
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net")\
        .option("bulkCopyBatchSize", 10000).option("bulkCopyTableLock", "true")\
        .option("bulkCopyTimeout", "6000000")\
        .save()
```

After executing this command the following error is returned:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.schemaString(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;)Ljava/lang/String;

Surprisingly, the dbo.test table gets deleted.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening. Same code works fine in another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.schemaString(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;)Ljava/lang/String;

The cause of error is ***version mismatch between the Spark SQL and JDBC spark connector.Also, The  `mode("overwrite")`  drops the table if already exists by default and re-creates a new one.***

**Here are some supported versions of JDBC spark connector ith respective spark version:**

- **Spark 2.4.x** : com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector:1.0.2
- **Spark 3.0.x** : com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0
- **Spark 3.1.x** : com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12 :1.2.0

**Resolution:**

If you are using Databricks runtime version greater than 10 then you need to downgrade it to **Databricks runtime version 9.1 LTS or down.** and use respective connector.

- I downgraded Databricks runtime version to 7.3 LTS:
  [image]
- Then installed appropriate library for spark 3.0.x which is `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0`
  [image]
- And tried your code its working fine.

```py
df_name.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode("overwrite")\
        .option("truncate", "false")\
        .option("url", "Azure_sql_url").option("dbtable", 'dbo.test')\
        .option("databaseName", "databasename")\
        .option("user", "username") \
        .option("password", "password") \
        .option("encrypt", "true")\
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net")\
        .option("bulkCopyBatchSize", 10000).option("bulkCopyTableLock", "true")\
        .option("bulkCopyTimeout", "6000000")\
        .save()
```

**My execution:**

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Or you can directly use **`dataframename.format("jdbc")`**

**Sample CODE:**

```py
df_name.write.format("jdbc").mode("overwrite")\
        .option("truncate", "false")\
        .option("url", "Azure_sql_url").option("dbtable", 'dbo.test')\
        .option("databaseName", "databasename")\
        .option("user", "username") \
        .option("password", "password") \
        .option("encrypt", "true")\
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net")\
        .option("bulkCopyBatchSize", 10000).option("bulkCopyTableLock", "true")\
        .option("bulkCopyTimeout", "6000000")\
        .save()
```

You can also refer similar issue here on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/issues/97) or this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271572/how-do-i-use-the-spark-connector-in-databricks-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-sql)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for the details @Pratik, I did downgraded the Databricks runtime version from 10.4 to 9.1 LTS with spark 3.1.2 and Scala 2.12. I have uninstalled old connectors and installed com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0 and I still face the same issue. I am unable to create a new table

Comment: Hey thanks @Pratik. It worked. After uninstall of previous library i haven't restarted my cluster. This now works. Thanks a lot :-)