# AWS Databricks: Table dropped when trying to overwrite with truncate flag set into Exasol

Tags: pyspark, databricks, exasol, spark-jdbc

I am trying to write dataframe data into a table in Exasol from AWS Databricks using pyspark while truncating the data before the overwrite. I am using the follow command:

```
`_df.write.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "**********")
    .option("dbtable", dbtable)
    .option("user", username)
    .option("password", password)
    .option("truncate", "true")
    .option("driver", "com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver")
    .mode("overwrite")  # You can use "overwrite", "append", "ignore", or "error"
    .save()`
```

This results in the table on Exasol to be dropped. If there is a solution that could send a truncate command using this jdbc connection prior to write (in append mode) that could also work.

The cluster and Exasol driver details are:

- 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)
- Exasol driver version: 7.1.20 (also tried 7.1.16 with same results)
- I found this to be the most relevant but this is targeted towards Azure Databricks:
  [Table gets deleted when trying to overwrite the data in it from databricks spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76486909/table-gets-deleted-when-trying-to-overwrite-the-data-in-it-from-databricks-spark)
- This was posted in the Dababricks community but I also did not see a solution for it:
  [https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/why-spark-save-modes-quot-overwrite-quot-always-drops-table/td-p/12749#:~:text=Overwrite%20is%20enabled%2C%20this%20option,data%20has%20a%20different%20schema](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/why-spark-save-modes-quot-overwrite-quot-always-drops-table/td-p/12749#:%7E:text=Overwrite%20is%20enabled%2C%20this%20option,data%20has%20a%20different%20schema).

Comment: Seems its not supported for Exasol,  `For unknown and unsupported JDBCDirect, the user option truncate is ignored.` check the docs for further info https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#:~:text=This%20is%20a,truncate%20is%20ignored.

Comment: @DataWrangler Thanks for your reply! How would you go as a workaroud for this if the standard jdbc does not work?

Comment: You could use a JDBC connection and then issue the `TRUNCATE TABLE` command prior to the write operation.